# Retrieve part of a link in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have the following link:

> http://anydomainname.com/user/username/about

I know that `$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI` will return `user/username/about`.

But I can't find a way to return the latest part of my link which is `about`.

How can I return it? I prefer a solution that does not require me to alter or add new functions in .php files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative to Marcin's answer using PHP's [basename() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) instead of substr/strrpos:

```
{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|basename}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|substr:($smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|strrpos:'/'+1)}
```

It finds the last `/` in this string and return everything after it.

It is working in Smarty 3.1.19